# How do I install .Net 4.0 onto Windows 10 version 22H2 with later .Net versions already installed?

Tags: .net, windows

I have been assigned M&O on a legacy ASP.Net 4.0 website. Currently, I have VS 2022 on my machine, with .Net Framework versions 3.5 and versions 4.6.1 through 4.8. I need to have the .Net Framework 4.0 on my machine in order for the solution to build appropriately, so that I am able to update it to the 4.8.

I downloaded from Microsoft the dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64 file, but when I try to install it, I get this window:[Windows message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IauKi.png)

I have tried disabling the earlier versions of the .Net framework by 'Turning on and off Windows features' window, but there was no difference in the resulting attempt to install.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You just can't. .NET Framework 4.x updates are in-place updates. There's built-in compatibility mode, but it's not perfect. If you really have to get a perfect 4.0 behavior, try installing older Windows version on a VM instead.

Comment: @Martheen how do I get the Compatibility mode turned on? I can use the VS 22 to update to the 4.8, but the website wont render.

Comment: Compatibility mode is automatic, apps declare what .NET Framework version they're built for, and the runtime will adjust the behavior. Unfortunately in your case, you might want to confirm that you can build and run the project with that exact source code first on the older VS it was originally developed from, and then slowly bring it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martheen, I ended up downloading and installing Visual Studio 2017. To my surprise, it came with the Developer Pack for .Net 4.0 when it installed the .Net Developer tools for that specific version of Visual Studio. After that install finished, I was able to open the solution in Visual Studio 2022, as a .Net 4.0 solution without having to update the Framework. Now I can make sure it compiles and runs before I go through the effort of updating the Framework to .Net 4.8, then to version 6.